# Iterate through a Python list, but the first element is at the end?

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to iterate through it from element 1 to the end, and then finish up with element 0.  Ie, essentially it's basic list iteration, except the very first element should be at the end.

I could do this with `for i in range(len(myList)):` and then adding 1 to i and checking for the edge case (that 's how I'd do in it C++), but was wondering if Python had some syntax which would make this concept easier to express?

Comment: `for i in list[1:] + list[:1]:`

Comment: @PacketLoss, IMHO it's the best answer - why don't to convert it to a regular answer and gain reputation points for it?

Comment: @kitfox a modulo operator can be handy in such situations, and the concept remains same in other languages. I've added as answer. Hope it adds some more value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way to achieve this, without the need for error handling/checks is to just use `slicing`.

```
_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in _list[1:] + _list[:1]: 
    print(i)

#2
#3
#4
#1
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a convenient syntax for this, but you could easily define your own: I've chosen the name `irotate` by analogy to [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), and written it in a way such that it can be provided a single-use iterable such as a generator expression.

```py
def irotate(iterable, k=1):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    initial_elements = [next(iterator) for _ in range(k)]
    yield from iterator
    yield from initial_elements
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> list(irotate(range(5)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
>>> for x in irotate(y**2 for y in range(5)): print(x)
... 
1
4
9
16
0
```

Comment: I would just replace `[next(iterator) for _ in range(k)]` with just `list(islice(iterator, k))`

Comment: Curiously, what is the argument for simply not using slicing for this? Noting both answers did not mention the simplicity of using sliced notation to achieve this. Is there a specific reason a method like the ones provided should be used over slicing?

Comment: @PacketLoss If it's a list then you can use slicing, sure; however, this way works with O(k) auxiliary space instead of O(n), and works when the iterable is not a list or tuple.

Comment: @kaya3 Perfect, thank you for expanding on the answer. +1

Comment: @PacketLoss Since your comment does answer the question in a simpler way, though, I suggest you convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and then adding 1 to i and checking for the edge case ...

If you want only get rid of the checking for the edge case, use `cycle()` from the `itertools` standard module to create an infinite iterator:

```
import itertools

my_list = [2, 10, "a"]
my_iter = itertools.cycle(my_list)   # 2, 10, "a", 2, 10, "a", 2, 10, "a", ...

next(my_iter)                        # drop the first element
for __ in range(len(my_list)):
    curr_elem = next(my_iter)
    print(curr_elem)                 # or do other activity with the current element
```

---

The output:

> ```
> 10
> a
> 2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One could use **modulo** to get something like this -

```
mylist = [i for i in range(8)]
for i in range(5):
  diff = i
  rotated = [mylist[i % len(mylist)] for i in range(diff, len(mylist)+diff)]
  print(rotated)
```

Output is -

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

It is creating another list. So, may wanna keep that in mind.